# How can I search applicationinfo by permissions?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-applicationinfo

I want to show the list of applications installed on user device which have the internet permission on their manifest file currently I am getting all of them by using this code:

```
PackageManager packageManager = mainActivity.getPackageManager();
            apps = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);
            Collections.sort(apps, new ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager));
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `getInstalledApplications()`, use `getInstalledPackages()`, including `GET_PERMISSIONS` in the `flags`. The resulting `PackageInfo` objects will have a `permissions` field filled in, for those packages that request permissions. `permissions` will be a `PermissionInfo[]`, and `PermissionInfo` has a `name` field you can check to see if it matches your desired permission. Something like this should work:

```
for (PackageInfo pkg : mgr.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS)) {
  for (PermissionInfo perm : pkg.permissions) { 
    if (Manifest.permission.INTERNET.equals(perm.name)) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```